# How to wrap my code into a proper await-able method?

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```cs
string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "MTZDATABASE.db3");
SQLiteConnection dbconn = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);              
dbconn.CreateTable<CustomerEntity>();
               
string str2 = "mystring";
DOTFORMS3.Common.CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString(str2);
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("tablename");
Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableQuery<CustomerEntityVR> tableQueryVR = new Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableQuery<CustomerEntityVR>();
dbconn.Close();
```

How can I put this code into an awaitable method that can be awaited? thx :)

Comment: Are any of the operations invoked by this code asynchronous?  If not then there's nothing to await.

Comment: unfortunately none of them can be awaited, so iwanted a way to make them await-able ?

Comment: What’s the underlying goal?  If all operations are synchronous then the code will “await” by design.  Do you mean that you want to make this operation asynchronous?

Comment: or in general how to put normal code into an waitable method

Comment: i got an `async` method that i want it to await the code above while it being done

Comment: Perhaps you could expand your example to demonstrate what you’re trying to describe?  Synchronous code doesn’t need to be awaited.  Maybe you’re trying to make this asynchronous?  It’s not clear.

Comment: yup my bad , i was just asking in general how to make a normal code awaited or used in a async method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the System.Threading.Tasks.Task library. Wrap your code inside of a CustomAsync method and await on the method call.The Task.Run() method queues the specified work to run on the ThreadPool and returns a task handle for that work.

```
public Task PerformDbOperationAsync()
{
    return Task.Run(
        () =>
        {
            string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "MTZDATABASE.db3");
            SQLiteConnection dbconn = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
            dbconn.CreateTable<CustomerEntity>();


            string str2 = "mystring";
            DOTFORMS3.Common.CreateStorageAccountFromConnectionString(str2);

            CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

            CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("tablename");
            Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableQuery<CustomerEntityVR> tableQueryVR = new Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table.TableQuery<CustomerEntityVR>();

            dbconn.Close();
        });
}
```